Python Celery route task using hostname
I'm currently utilizing Celery for task management within my application, and I'm facing a challenge regarding task distribution to specific workers based on their unique hostnames. In my use case, I'm deploying multiple worker containers for a particular application. These containers are required to connect to various VPNs for specific requests or processing tasks.
The challenge arises from the dynamic nature of container deployment, where each container's hostname is unique and dynamically assigned and it is stored on database with metadata information to be used by the application to select which worker should run a particular task.
Given this scenario, I'm seeking a solution to send tasks directly to a specific worker based on it's hostname. This would ensure efficient task distribution, even in dynamic deployment environments where workers may connect to different VPNs dynamically and have different hostname each time.
The logic to select the worker is already in place.
The logic to create container/worker is already in place.
The logic to requeue a task that is sorted to an invalid queue is already in place.
Scenario
Workers

Worker01 (hostname=a333) connected to VPN 1
Worker02 (hostname=b999) connected to VPN 2
Worker03 (hostname=c777) connected to VPN 3
Worker04 (hostname=c444) connected to VPN 1

Tasks

Task01 needs to run on Worker01|04 (identified by it's hostname)
Task02 needs to run on Worker02 (identified by it's hostname)
Task03 needs to run on Worker01|04 (identified by it's hostname)
Task04 needs to run on Worker03 (identified by it's hostname)

I've been working on configuring different exchanges and routing keys for my Celery setup, but I seem to be encountering some issues.
Despite my efforts, it appears that something is missing in the configuration.
Thank you in advance for any help!

Based on your example: You have logic that determines which of three VPNs a task should be processed with. Could you use this logic to send each task to one of three queues, each corresponding to a different VPN, and then have logic that determines which queue a worker process consumes from when the worker container is created?

E.g. Worker01 and Worker04 both consume from the same queue, so sending a task to that queue will guarantee that it is processed by one of those two workers

You are correct in assume that and that logic works great, but all the workers will consume the same queue and each one will be connected to a different vpn, that’s why I need to sort the worker using its hostname, because it was stored at database previously, I know it’s possible, just missing some point, the reason to it is that the vpn is dynamically attached to different countries and/or networks given thousands of possibilities and the logic to handle it is already in place. I’ll probably find a different way, maybe creating dynamic name to queue and store it on database. I’ll test.
